# What to do with rotisserie chicken juices

Tags: chicken-stock

I bought 2 rotisserie chickens yesterday for the meat.  I use it for chicken soup.  I saved the juices at the bottom of the pans in the refrigerator.  This morning it is a gelatin with just a bit of not so hard fat on the top.  I threw away the fat, but is the gelatin good for anything?  Is it a kind of stock?  Can I add it to the soup?

Comment: It's effectively like stock, and can be used in situations where you just need a little extra flavorful liquid.  (eg, soup, rice, etc.)

Comment: I never save mine because we always wind up adding it to potatoes, roasted vegetables or rice we have with the chicken, so it all gets eaten.

Answer (score 1):

> I threw away the fat, but is the gelatin good for anything? Is it a kind of stock?

Oh yeah.. you can use it. That is some great chicken stock. You just don't recognize it as such, because it's cold, which gels it.

When that gel is in a heated dish, it will taste very good. Superior to any canned broth, better than any bullion cube.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the liquid anywhere you'd use stock. However, do be aware that supermarket rotisserie chickens probably have various things injected into them to improve flavor and texture. There's certainly nothing hazardous, but the flavors of the injected liquid may clash with the flavors of whatever you're using the "stock" for. So, taste it, correct the seasonings, and then use away.