# What to do with juices from roasting pork

Tags: stock

I cook a few kilograms of pork loin at one time, and I get a considerable amount of juice. It's liquid while it's hot, and it's gel when it's cold. What can I do with it?

You can [do a lot with chicken stock](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/71304/what-to-do-with-rotisserie-chicken-juices), but what can you do with pork stock?

Comment: It makes a really good pilaf.  Or soup.

Answer (score 3):

Use it like chicken stock?  Pork stock is delicious...but the meat juices are not yet a stock.  Use the bones, some aromatic veg., and the juices.  Make a stock. Use the stock in any application that you want porky goodness.